# Get the list of Groups for the given UserPrincipal

Tags: c#, active-directory, userprincipal

I want to get the list of groups which the user is in.

This is my code:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.ac.uk",   "DC=mydomain,DC=AC,DC=UK", "user", "password");

UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "MyUser");

PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = user.GetGroups();

foreach(Principal p in results)
{
   Response.Write(p.Name);
}
```

When I run, I got the following error at the line `Response.Write(p.Name);`

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

When I checked the count of the results, it returned 9 and the first group is `DomainUsers`.

How can I iterate all 9 groups in the list? Thanks.

The following is the list of users I get:

[image]

Comment: how you initialize PrincipalContext?

Comment: PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.ac.uk", "DC=mydomain,DC=AC,DC=UK", "user", "password");

Comment: The name attribute may not have been populated (perhaps because it was from a different domain than the one you queried??). Try asking for the DisplayName or DistinguishedName or SamAccountName or SID.

Comment: I have tried these name but the error is still the same.  When I checked in the debug view, the following is the error I get:    Name ( '((System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal)((new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal>(results)).Items[1])).Name' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' )

Comment: I guess it's because your "user" account doesn't have enough permission to read the group objects.  Do you see `DistinguishName` attribute and `Guid` attribute?

Comment: i have the same error - i get the collection of groups, but can't get their properties. did you solve this problem?

Comment: @donRumatta var theDirectoryEntry = groupPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject(); then theDirectoryEntry.Properties["propertyName"].Value as ???. Of course you'll have to iterate through the collection of group principals.

Answer (score 6):

When omitting the LDAP container property as described in PrincipalContext Class, the user running the code must have read permissions to both the default `User` Container (i.e. `CN=Users,DC=yourDomain,DC=COM`) and the `Computers` Container (i.e. `CN=Computers,DC=yourDomain,DC=COM`).

If the user does not have the required permissions you will get the following error messages:

> The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
>
> - ‘context.Container’ threw an exception of type ‘System.NullReferenceException’    string
>     {System.NullReferenceException}
> - ((new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView(groups)).Items[5]).Description’
>     threw an exception of type
>     ‘System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException’    string
>     {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}

Comment: If someone deletes the computers container in the domain in question, you will get this error as well. For heaven's sake... Someone deleted the thing.

Comment: Anyone attempting to use `this.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole("ad group name")` and it always returns false with no exception thrown, this is a possible cause. Restoring the CN and permissions fixed this for me.

Comment: The link to the blog seems to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
foreach(Principal p in results)
{ 
   if (p is GroupPrincipal) 
      Response.Write(p.DisplayName); 
}
```

I know it sounds dumb, but it has worked for me in the past. Your results look like it only actually found 1 security group and 8 "other" types of groups. Those "other" groups may not possess those attributes.

Comment: For me, the name was better (DisplayName was empty: `user.GetGroups().OfType<GroupPrincipal>().Select(p => p.Name));`