# Principal.IsInRole("AD Group Name") always returns false, no exceptions thrown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In a Web API controller I needed to determine the role membership using an AD group that contained members from multiple domains in another forest.

`this.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole(roleName)`

returned false and no indication of an error could be found. The code above *did* work with other AD groups, though. I then modified the code to loop through the group in question and received an exception.

```
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, roleName);
if (group != null)
{
    foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
    {
         if (p != null && currentUserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName == p.UserPrincipalName) 
        {
            roles.Add(roleName);
            break;
         }
      }


 }
```

> The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

I determined it was the exception was being thrown on a group member from a specific domain. I removed said individual and code executed normally. I added another account form the same domain as the first and the error returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for the given error message I found the following [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25139751/330430). The top answer states.

> When omitting the LDAP container property as described in `PrincipalContext` Class, the user running the code must have read permissions to both the default `User` Container (i.e. `CN=Users,DC=yourDomain,DC=COM`) and the `Computers` Container (i.e. `CN=Computers,DC=yourDomain,DC=COM`).

Using Active Directory Users and Computers I browsed the AD of the problem domain and could not see any `Computers` container. I contacted IS and informed them of this and they restored the directory to a good state. At that point `this.RequestContext.Principal.IsInRole(roleName)` worked as expected and I was able to evaluate role membership.

Edit: OMG! This also fixed an issue with the SharePoint user profile service not syncing user details from members in the same domain. I have been trying for two years to track down the cause of the the user profile error with no success.